# Found a user posting Amazon affiliate links everwhere

Tags: discussion, status-completed, spam, link-only-answers

https://stackexchange.com/users/5074398/venus-house?tab=activity

I've raised flags on the sites I'm already a user of, but as they're acting elsewhere thought it easiest to write here. None of their answers are useful, and all have Amazon affiliate links

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Heh.

Idiots.

Had they realized that we *automatically re-write Amazon affiliate links to our own*, they probably wouldn't have bothered. Might have a look in the logs to see what the original affiliate ID was, Amazon doesn't take kindly to that.

Suspending / nuking / molecular destabilizing in the works. Thanks for the head's up.

Comment: They're using a URL shortener, so it's not getting rewritten.

Comment: Just noticed that after ... oh never mind.